# Set bearer token after login

Tags: javascript, axios

I have set a base service using axois and set a bearer token in it but when it  calls a user API then I get unauthorized access because of `null` token but I have already set a token in local storage

Base

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API;
const token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken');
export default axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        Authorization  : 'Bearer '+token
    },
})
```

In login.vue

```
 let res = await loginService.checkLogin(usrname,password)
 this.loader = false
 localStorage.setItem('usertoken',res.data.data.token)
```

For user

```
import baseService from "./baseService";

export default {
    fetchUsers(){
        return baseService.post( `${'user/get-all-users'}`,{
            limit:1000
        }).then(function(response){
            return response
        }).catch(function(error){
            return error.response
        })
    },
```

Comment: please check your network tab in the browser for debug the request.check whether request header has the token as expected

Answer (score 2):

```
export default axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization'  : 'Bearer '+token
    },
})
```

Use `'Authorization'` .

Or you can also use

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+token;
```

Comment: I had already try this but after login token is blank but if I refresh then it works fine

Comment: Just remove const and use let instead. `let token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken');` Since value is set to empty once application loads, the value of token never changes due to use of const. After reload, since localstorage has the value, the token const gets the value and works.

Comment: Yes , you need to set `usertoken ` to empty when user first loads the applications & when logouts. Since, localstorage is not cleared automatically unlike session storage we need to do this manually. Now, after clearing re-set the token after login. So that localstorage always has the most recent token.

Comment: I cleared local storage after logout but still, it took old value

Comment: First remove const, and change it to var or let. Otherwise logout will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If the token variable is set at the start of a file it takes the original value. As a result your usertoken is not reactive, its not getting the new value from localstorage. I did this with my app to fix the same issue I faced

```
import axios from "axios";

const baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API;

export default axios.create({
    baseURL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        Authorization  : 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('usertoken')
    },
})
```

Comment: Above code give an error

loginService.js?d28e:5 Uncaught (in promise) 

TypeError: baseService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.post is not a function at Object.checkLogin (loginService.js?d28e:5)

Comment: Ah ok so my axios is returning a function with a return value. Changed it

Comment: ok but is this an improvement of your previous situation, cause I am a bit confused on where this refresh is taking place. Wouldn't you be redirecting your route after login?

Comment: I redirect to dashboard after login but when I click on users it shows null token